# VS 2010 reporting tool

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting, report, visual-studio-2010

I have an ASP.NET project in VS 2010 SP 1 and I need to implement several reports.
The interesting fact is that I'm only manipulating objects and I have no database direct access.

One C# object can have other child objects or even lists of child objects and is very likely that those details should show up in reports.
The classic example is Author - Book: one book may be written by multiple authors and one author may have wrote multiple books.

Are you aware of any reporting tools that make designing reports from objects more easy?

Answer (score 2):

What about the [built-in ReportViewer components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671.aspx)? They support both

- database sources and
- object sources (which seems to be what you need).

Here's an MSDN tutorial:

- [Walkthrough: Using a Business Object Data Source with the ReportViewer Web Server Control in Local Processing Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251692.aspx)

Comment: In the msdn sample there is no object that contains a list of objects. In order to include that into the report i would need to use subreports. I'm concerned that relying on subreports will work against me later on during development.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Stimulsoft Reports](http://www.stimulsoft.com/ShowArticle.aspx?id=0150) could be useful.

> Stimulsoft reporting now supports binding to any .NET class; this feature is called business objects in the report designer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with data objects and your needs are simple take a look at DevExpress (disclaimer - I'm the CTO at one of their competitors).